# CiviCRM Event auto public on WordPress after saving

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Our CiviEvents are being made public on our Wordpress whenever we save them. They are all listed as private, because only our community are meant to see them.

When we edit the event in CiviCRM it automatically makes the event public in wordpress on save.

Any thoughts?

Addition information as per the comment. 
We are using the following plugins - 
CiviCRM Event Organiser V0.4.1 - https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser
AND
Event Organiser V3.6.2 - https://wp-event-organiser.com/
*This one does have an update available.

Comment: You say "public in WordPress", which suggests you're using a WordPress plugin to display CiviCRM events.  Could you please update your question with the plugin you're using so folks can give you better suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Please update to the latest versions of both plugins and then let me know the exact steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please update to the latest version of CiviCRM Event Organiser:

https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser

This should respect the existing post status of your Event Organiser events.

Comment: @heidi-prowse If this answer fixes your issue, could you mark it as such. Thanks!